# Generating Covariance plot

Tags: plotting

```
 n =1000;
 i =1;
 taskA = Table[RandomReal[],{n}];

 avg = 1/ n * Sum(taskA[[i]];);

 ListPlot[Table[1/(n-tau) * Sum((taskA[[i]]-avg)*(taskA[[i+tau]] - avg)),
 {tau, 1,100}], Joined->True, AxesLabel->"Covariance Function"]
```

This code is supposed to generate the following graph,

[image]

**But, in actuality, it is generating a blank image,**

[image]

**What has possibly gone wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few arguments mistaken.  The Table function, SUM function

```
n = 1000;
i = 1;
taskA = Table[RandomReal[], {i, n}];

avg = Mean[taskA]

ListPlot[Table[
  1/(n)*Sum[(taskA[[i]] - avg)*(taskA[[i + tau]] - avg), n], {tau, 1, 
   100}], Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> "Covariance Function"]
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dRtRDht.png

Comment: Copy and paste into your notebook. The graph will show. Compare your code to my. There are a few mistakes in your format.  Which one you have problems seen how it works?

Comment: Also your code seems to be generating different output.  http://i.imgur.com/vtGvqsE.png

Comment: There was a mistake in your covariance equation. Look at the help for CovarianceFunction

Comment: My question was, the image-link I posted in the comment seems to be different from your formula. So, how was it working?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question.  The images will not be the same because you are using a RandomReal function. Therefore the data set in the taskA list will not be the same every time that is executed.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks! I got it!